# Setting up conan in a fresh gitlab container

Tags: python, sqlite, gitlab, conan

I have been attempting to get conan running inside of a docker container that also runs gitlab. I have been attempting to follow these two guides here:

https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/     ****Using the Selinux version, im on RHEL 7
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/conan_repository/   *********Only get as far as the actual installing of conan

Whenever I then try to run the conan --version command I get an error message stating "no module named _sqlite3". So in order to try and fix that I have tried installing pysqlite3, libsqlite-dev, sqlite3, pretty much any sqlite named package (within the container of course) I can think of but to no success.

Here is the actual stack trace from the conan call in the event that it may give someone some insight into my issue.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/conan", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('conan==1.32.0', 'console_scripts', 'conan')())
  File "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 473, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2843, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2447, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2453, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conans/conan.py", line 7, in <module>
    from conans.client.command import main
  File "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conans/client/command.py", line 16, in <module>
    from conans.client.conan_api import Conan, default_manifest_folder, _make_abs_path, ProfileData
  File "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conans/client/conan_api.py", line 11, in <module>
    from conans.client.cache.cache import ClientCache
  File "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conans/client/cache/cache.py", line 16, in <module>
    from conans.client.store.localdb import LocalDB
  File "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conans/client/store/localdb.py", line 2, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this means that you have the python files for the module, but missing the compiled native extension

Comment: I'm assuming you're referring to the .so file. If that assumption is correct, how would I go about manually adding it so that the module is detected?